# Does LuaTeX + OpenType always calculate inter-word spacing stretch and shrink as 1/2 and 1/3 of the nominal space?

Tags: fonts, luatex, opentype

As far as I know, OpenType does not have the concept of inter-word spacing stretch and shrink, only the normal amount. And `\fontdimen` 3 and 4 are calculated by luatex or the fontloader instead. And they are always a half and a third of the normal amount of the font, which is provided by the font.

It the above assumption correct? I tried a few fonts and examine the fontdimens, it seems to be the case. But I cannot find a definite reference.

The stretch and shrink are quite adequate for CM/LM, which has a normal space 0.333em. But they are too much for most humanist faces. For example, Arno has 0.199em and Minion has 0.227em. A third shrink makes the words fit too tight. Plus/Minus 15% is a lot better. Though I can systematically set the word space to the desired range through fontspec's WordSpace option, I still like to confirm that the usual value is always a half and a third

Comment: I think so, got a bit lost but looks like luaotfload's `fontloader-reference.lua`  has `parameters.space_stretch=1*units/2  
    parameters.space_shrink=1*units/3  `

Comment: Imho fontspec resets them for ttfamily to zero and @DavidCarlisle wanted or did add similar settings in the new format.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer `fontspec` reset them for ttfamily through its `default` setting, which can be overridden by users. I think it is generally desirable, if one really want to have a so called "monospace"

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Though I disagree with `fontspec` on that though. I think mono spaced fonts need more elasticity than most, except in code listing, which in most environments will be reset through `spaceskip` anyway.

Comment: In my opinion a "monospace" should be mono spaced and should be used in raggedright context, so elasticity is not needed. Beside this: cmtt has had zero stretch/shrink fontdimen since the dawn of times and it would be awkward if with xelatex/lualatex the default would be different. (BTw: just test, in the newest latex format lmtt has zero fontdimens)

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I think it depends how it is used. In your case I agree if set for extended text, it should have zero elasticity. I was thinking of a mono spaced font used sparsely in normal text, for the purpose of showing a short code snippet etc., In that case, I would rather it has some more elasticity, especially shrinkabilty, since they tend to fit a lot looser than the surrounding text.

Comment: Do you really want a monospaced font in that case?

Comment: @cfr To tell the truth, I am a bit undecided, and shifting back and forth with different options.

Answer (score 3):

`luaotfload`'s `fontloader-reference.lua` has

```
parameters.space_stretch=1*units/2
parameters.space_shrink=1*units/3
```

so sets the stretch and shrink as you suggest. As discussed in comments latex sets the stretch and shrink to 0 for monospace fonts.